# Avoid deadlock with Future { blocking {} }

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I am using the following code to get a JDBC connection, inside a `blocking` block, and pass that connection to a `fn: Connection => Future[_]`. After fn finishes I'd like to commit/rollback the transaction and close the connection.

```scala
  def withTransactionAsync[T](fn: Connection => Future[T]): Future[T] =
    Future {
      blocking {
        ds.getConnection
      }
    }.flatMap { conn =>
      fn(conn)
        .map { r => conn.commit(); conn.close(); r }
        .recoverWith {
          case e: Throwable =>
            conn.rollback()
            conn.close()
            throw e
        }
    }
```

I am using a separate execution context based on a `ForkJoinPool`.

With enough calls, this code goes into a deadlock. Intuitively, this makes sense. The first future, with the `getConnection` call, gets blocked while waiting for available connections, while available connections are waiting for available threads in the ExecutionContext to run the `commit(); close()` block to free the connection and free a thread in the execution context for `getConnection` to run. I verified this is the case with a thread dump.

The only way I found around this problem is to run everything on the same `Future {}` and therefore avoid switching the context:

```scala
  def withTransactionAsync[T](fn: Connection => Future[T]): Future[T] =
    Future {
      blocking {
        val conn = ds.getConnection

        try {
          conn.setAutoCommit(false)
          val r = Await.result(fn(conn), Duration.Inf)
          conn.commit()
          r
        } catch {
          case e: Throwable =>
            conn.rollback()
            throw e
        } finally
          conn.close()
      }
    }
```

But this way I am blocking on `Await.result`. I suppose this is not a big problem because I am blocking inside a `blocking` block, but I am afraid this would have unforeseen consequences and is not necessarily what the caller of this API expects.

Is there a way around this deadlock without using `Await` and just rely on Future composition?

I suppose a case could be made that this this function not be accepting `Connection => Future[T]` but only a `Connection => T`, but I'd like to keep that API.

If I increase the size of the `ForkJoinPool` enough, it works, but that size is difficult to calculate/predict for all workloads and I don't want to have a `ForkJoinPool` many times the size of my database pool.

Comment: Just use different thread pools for your blocking and non-blocking code.

Comment: Is it really necessary to open and close a new connection every time? Seems very inefficient. It feels like a `Task` model is more suitable here.

Comment: I am using different thread pools, it doesn't stop this problem.
I am not closing the connection actually, my data source is a pool (hikari cp). `close` just returns the connection to the pool.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make sense. The whole point of a `blocking` operation is that the EC spawns a new thread for that call, leaving the existing threads for non-blocking calls. So this may create loads of threads, but it shouldn't deadlock because there should always be a thread to execute the non-blocking code. Unless, of course, the non-blocking code actually blocks e.g. because `fn` blocks or returns a blocking `Future` or one of the `conn.` operations blocks.

Comment: @Tim getConnection blocks after maxConnections waiting for a free connection in the pool. Also `fn` has blocking code because it's accesing the db and my jdbc calls are all sync, the driver is not async.

Comment: @sarveshseri That actually helped. Not by using separate ECs for blocking or non blocking, but running the getConnection and commit/close calls in different ECs it actually works because they don't deadlock on each other.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the "non-blocking" code is actually blocking, because that is the only way there could be a deadlock. If the "non-blocking" code runs to completion without waiting for any external event then this code won't deadlock.
TL;DR: Put the "non-blocking" code in a `blocking` clause and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `fn` is blocking code. But it is not inside a `blocking` clause, so it will tie up one of the main threads in the pool. If this happens enough times, the pool will run out of threads and the system will deadlock.

So the call to `fn` and the code that follows needs to be inside a `blocking` clause so that a separate thread is created for it and the main threads remain available for non-blocking code.

Given the amount of blocking code, it is probably worth looking at a `Task` model with a thread per connection rather than a thread per pending operation, so that the number of threads is constrained. This is basically a work-around for the fact that `getConnection` is synchronous, which is a problem with HikariCP.

Comment: Indeed this is all blocking code, due to JDBC APIs, not hikaricp though. Wrapping `fn` in a `blocking` block doesn't change this, because it just creates more threads but at some point the ECs don't create any more threads the calls deadlock. I receive a `fn`, I cannot force the caller of this api to wrap their code in `blocking`.

What works is running `getConnection` and `commit/close` in different ECs, then they don't deadlock waiting for each other.

I also cannot use a `Task` model, the `fn: Connection => Future[_]` API is forced on my code.

Comment: My suggestion was that you wrap `fn` in `blocking` in your code; you can't do anything to stop `fn` from calling blocking code in a non-blocking context. It is possible to use the `Task` model with that interface: When `withTransactionAsync` is called you create a `Promise[T]` and return the `Future[T]` from that promise and put the promise/fn on a queue to be executed. When there is a connection free, call `fn` with that connection and complete the `Promise` with the result. This removes the need for a thread waiting for `getConnection` which, in turn, removes one possible cause for deadlock.